# Authentication in Solr 5

Tags: security, solr

I have only one server, Solr server. Is it possible to enable Authentication and Authorization for Solr 5 **without installing ZooKeeper**?

I know that one possible way is to configure, for example, IP table and give access to the server from a certain host (or hosts). But I am interested in Solr's capabilities without any external servers like ZooKeepers.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your container to do authentication yourself, but the only bundled support in Solr requires running Solr in SolrCloud mode (meaning that it has to either use an external Zookeeper or the internal, bundled one). From [the reference guide about Authentication and Authorization]:(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Authentication+and+Authorization+Plugins)

> To use these plugins, you must create a security.json file and upload it to ZooKeeper. This means that authentication and authorization is supported in SolrCloud mode only.

You could also bind Solr to localhost (as Solr shouldn't be exposed on public ips) and then use nginx or Apache to reverse proxy any requests and perform authentication. Configuration would depend on the chosen httpd and how it configures Basic HTTP Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install any external zookeeper to enable authentication and authorization in your solr server. Internal zookeeper works perfectly fine.

http://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/

I hope this helps.

Comment: I read this article before, but I decided not to rely on Solr's security mechanism, since its documentation is very poor, it is not clear what is what and how it works. I have no time to look through tons of code trying to figure out how it works and what it does, neither am I a Java programmer. I wish Solr's documentation would be more helpful, simple, and clear with examples, and its security mechanism should be revised and made more clear and simpler. For now we used other ways to protect Solr server.